# A, seemingly binary, bizzare array

Tags: cipher, music

Your friend in band class has been writing on a piece of paper, then hands it to you. On the paper reads:

```
0 1 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1
```

What message is encoded into the numbers?

Hint:

> Your friend's sheet music is in Eb and the lowest note they can play on their instrument is an Bb.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used two reasonings, and always ended with a slightly cryptic message, namely

> CACHED.

The first method was to look up this chart

> http://www.ultimatesongwriting.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/saxophone_fingering_chart.png

and using the six bottommost circles of the patterns in "part 2", I interpreted the message as

> "CACBED", which made no sense, until I remembered that [a "B" is actually called "H" on the German scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_note#12-tone_chromatic_scale)

---

The other method was a brute force dictionary attack on a substitution cipher. First, I read the data as columns, because reading it as lines would give the same letter three times in a row. Then, the pattern of the letters is "121345".

Assuming that the music theme is of some relevance, I then searched my spell checker word list (Ubuntu's "british-english-insane", with the last bit referring to the number of words included) for words consisting of names for musical notes that match the letter pattern "121345". I found two, and the other one was "AFACED", which isn't really a dictionary word. The other match was, of course, the same word as found by the other method.

Std. disclaimer: I may very well have made a mistaken assumption somewhere along the way, since the resulting message is a bit opaque, to say the least.

Comment: Other vaguely music related words with that pattern are adagio, bebops, evenly, fifths, ninths, oboist,  pipers, mambos, A major. Not sure if this helps...

Comment: Pupils eyeing papers: cockup awaits. Gigues awaken babies. Vivace amazes. Idiots cackle. :-)